# sshfs: will a mount overwrite existing files? Can I tell it to exclude a certain subfolder?

Tags: sshfs

I'm running Ubuntu and have a remote CentOS system which stores (and has access to) various files and network locations. I have SSH access to the CentOS machine and want to be able to work locally on Ubuntu.

I'm trying to mirror a remote directory structure. The remote directory is structured:

```
/my_data/user/*
```

And I want to replicate this structure locally (a lot of scripts rely on absolute paths).

However, for reasons of speed, I want a certain subfolder, for example:

```
/my_data/user/sourcelibs/
```

To be stored locally on disk. I know the sourcelibs subfolder doesn't change much (but the rest might). So I can comfortably rsync it:

```
mkdir -p /my_data/user/sourcelibs/
rsync -r remote_user@remote_host:/my_data/user/sourcelibs/ /my_data/user/sourcelibs/
```

My question is, if I use sshfs to mount /my_data/user:

```
sudo sshfs -o allow_other,default_permissions, remote_user@remote_host:/my_data/user /my_data/user

Will it overwrite my existing files? Is there a way to have sshfs mount but exclude certain subfolders?
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `sshfs` will  overwrite existing files. I have almost the same use case and just tested this myself. BTW, you'll need to add `-o nonempty` to your `sshfs` command since the destination dir `/my_data/user` already exists.

What I found to work is make a copy of the remote directory excluding the large sub dirs. IDK if keeping 2 copies in sync on the remote machine is feasible for your use case? But if you'll mostly be updating on your local machine and rarely making changes remotely, that could work.